# Use bash variable in AWK expression

Tags: bash, variables, awk, scripting, escaping

I tried the following snippet in a shell script but `awk` didn't find `$REF`

```sh
REF=SEARCH_TEXT
echo "some text" | awk '/$REF/{print $2}'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing a shell script variable into an awk command](http://superuser.com/questions/203819/passing-a-shell-script-variable-into-an-awk-command)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You question is worded **really** poor...

Anyway, I think you want this:

```
REF=SEARCH_TEXT
echo "some text" | awk "/$REF/{print \$2}"
```

*Note the escaping of `$2` and the double quotes.*

or this:

```
REF=SEARCH_TEXT
echo "some text" | awk "/$REF/"'{print $2}'
```

*Note the judicious use of double and single quotes and no escaping on `$2`.*

You have to use shell expansion, as otherwise it would encompass exporting a shell variable and using it from the environment with awk - which is *overkill* in this situation:

```
export REF=SEARCH_TEXT
echo "some text" | awk '{if (match($0, ENVIRON["REF"])) print $2}'
```

I think awk does not support variables in /.../ guards. *Please correct me if I'm wrong.*

Comment: $2 works fine with and without the \. The question is about $REF, which is not expended by awk. thx

Comment: @Fritschy: For many people using the Internet, English is not their first language; some people use Google to translate their question. ;-)

Comment: vehomzzz, when using double quotes - which was what I suggested in roder to let the shell expand `$REF` correctly, you do have to escape `$2` - end prevent the shell from expanding it.

Comment: @Dave - OK, I didn't anticipate google's translation. Thanks for explaining ;)

Comment: vehomzzz - no offense really :) - it's not my first language, not even my second, which might be obvious ;)

Answer (score 54):

Instead of quoting games in the shell, use the `-v` option to pass the shell variable as an awk variable:

```
awk -v ref="$REF" 'match($0, ref) {print $2}'
```

If `$REF` is just text and not a regular expression, use the `index()` function instead of `match()`.

Comment: Could you pls advice me how to do this in my case? left=1; right=4; grep ETM21CH01EPU3Z -A1 SLf_454.fna | tail -n 1 | awk '{print substr($0,1,4)}'
works and outputs GTTG, but the version with variables does not, thank you:  left=1; right=4; grep ETM21CH01EPU3Z -A1 SLf_454.fna | tail -n 1 | awk -v l="$left" r="$right" '{print substr($0,l,r)}'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{print substr($0,l,r)}' for reading

Comment: @Perlnika, you need a `-v` for each variable: `awk -v l="$left" -v r="$right"`

Answer (score 1):

In `gawk`, you have the `ENVIRON` array, e.g. `awk 'END{print ENVIRON["REF"]}' /dev/null` will print your variable if you've `export`ed it out from the shell to sub-processes.

Comment: This works too (and the variable doesn't have to be exported if you do `REF=value awk '...'`). But I'd recommend the `-v` switch as the general solution.