# variable declaration in awk command

Tags: awk

I am facing the problem in `awk` command. Actually I used a variable `DELETION_COMMAND` and value of that variable is `rm -rf`. After that I am trying to execute the below line then it gives an error. While if am using the `rm` as a value of same variable `DELETION_COMMAND`. then it works fine.

```
awk '{print "'${DELETION_COMMAND}'"" ""'${COMPLETE_PATH}'""/"$1"/*"}' ${DB_FEED_FILE} > ${TEMP_FEED_FILE}
```

**Error :**

```
awk: {print "rm
awk:        ^ unterminated string
```

Please suggest.
 Where am I wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use bash variable from within AWK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519408/use-bash-variable-from-within-awk)

Comment: a bit off topic, but be sure to put a -- argument between "DELETION_COMMAND" (or as part of the DELETION_COMMAND variable) and the path to signify the last flag, else you might wind up trying to delete '/my/path/ ; rm -rf'  (note that symbols and spaces are completely valid characters in paths)

Answer (score 1):

The highlighing already indicates your error. You put the awk expression between single quotes and then uses single quotes in the expression. Awk thinks your expression is this:

```
awk '{print "'
```

To solve this, escape the single quotes using a backslash.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd...But I didn't get your point..Can you please write the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-v` flag to pass shell vars to `awk`, and don't forget the quoting:

```
awk -v com="${DELETION_COMMAND}" -v path="${COMPLETE_PATH}" '{ print com, path, "/", $1, "/" }' "${DB_FEED_FILE}" > "${TEMP_FEED_FILE}"
```

Comment: Thanks Steve...but same command is running for "rm" value. so what is the problem with "rm -rf" value.

Comment: @sumitvedi: The problem is that your variable is unquoted: In your example, you'd need: `awk '{print '"${DELETION_COMMAND}"' ...`. HTH.