# Bash script, for a given group name, print all the users and the groups they are in including the given one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am creating a script that takes a group name, and it should  print all the users and the groups they are in including the given one, but I still can't figure out how to do it properly, here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# contentFile is the file you are trying to read
# contentFile will be a parameter supplied by the user
# thus we leave it empty for now
groupName=

## List of options the program will accept;
## those options that take arguments are followed by a colon
## in this case, group name: n
optstring=n:

## The loop calls getopts until there are no more options on the command line
## Each option is stored in $opt, any option arguments are stored in OPTARG
while getopts $optstring opt
do
    case $opt in
        n) groupName=$OPTARG ;; ## $OPTARG contains the argument to the option (contentFile in this context)
        *) exit 1 ;; ## exit if anything else other than -f file name was entered
    esac
done

groups=$(cat /etc/group | cut -d: -f1)

for user in $(cat /etc/passwd  | cut -d: -f1)
do 
    echo grep -q $groupName $groups
    if [ $? = 0  ]
    then
        echo "- grupuri:" "$user" "\n;"
    fi
done
```

Output I am getting

```
grep -q root adm wheel kmem tty utmp audio disk input kvm lp optical render storage uucp video users sys mem ftp mail log smmsp proc games lock network floppy scanner power systemd-journal rfkill nobody dbus bin daemon http systemd-journal-remote systemd-network systemd-resolve systemd-timesync systemd-coredump uuidd dnsmasq rpc gdm ntp avahi colord cups flatpak geoclue git nm-openconnect nm-openvpn polkitd rtkit usbmux fsociety postgres locate mongodb dhcpcd docker openvpn mysql
```

- grupuri: mysql \n;

expected output:

```
whoopsie - grupuri:whoopsie;
colord - grupuri:colord;
sssd - grupuri:sssd;
geoclue - grupuri:geoclue;
pulse - grupuri:audio;pulse;pulse-access;
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: What doesn't work? Any errors?

Comment: Can you not just do cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs groups?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I am not getting errors, but I am not getting the output or data I am looking for. I updated the question to include the output I am getting.

Comment: @RamanSailopal, it only prints the "root" group

Comment: It should print the groups of each user found in /etc/passwd

Comment: @RamanSailopal, it only prints 'root' string. it is odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following bash script;

```
group='certuser'
for user in $(awk -F ':' "/${group}/"'{print $4}' /etc/group | tr ',' '\n'); do
    echo "$(groups $user)"
done
```

Where

1. `awk -F ':' '/certuser/ { print $4 }' /etc/group`

   > Gets each users in the **$group** ('certuser') group, seperated by a `,`
   >
   > Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to remove group info so we're only keeping users
2. `| tr ',' '\n'`

   > Pipes that csv to the for-loop
3. `echo "$(groups $user)"`

   > Use the [`groups`](https://ss64.com/bash/groups.html) command to get all users in that group

Comment: Thank you for your response. May I ask how can I make the group name a variable, for example awk -F ':' '/$groupName/ { print $4 }' /etc/group; instead of awk -F ':' '/certuser/ { print $4 }' /etc/group? Thank you.

Comment: Sure! Please check my edit, you can use [a bash variable to create an AWK expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519408/use-bash-variable-in-awk-expression)!

Comment: awk -v grp="certuser" -F ':' '$0 ~ grp { if ($4 !="") { split($4,map,",");for (i in map) { print map[i] } } }' /etc/group | xargs groups allows execution in one go.

Comment: @0stone0, can I please ask you if there is a way I could return the groups string as in my output in the question? (with the ';' delimiter instead of space). I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getent` command to retrieve information about groups and users. In particular, `getent group` queries the groups, while `getent passwd` queries the users.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
group=$1
gid=$(getent group "$1" | cut -d: -f3)
getent passwd \
| awk -F: -v gid=$gid '($4==gid){print $1}' \
| xargs -n1 groups
```